# Using Haxe code in Java

Tags: java, haxe

Is there any way to use compiled Haxe code in a Java application (instead of vice-versa?) I want to write a library of functions in Haxe, compile the Haxe code to Java, and then use the compiled Haxe library in a Java application.

Comment: To search for a specific function in a source folder, you can use `grep -r "myFunction" *java` - this will return all occurrences of `myFunction` in the source folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can.

You just have to use [Haxe / Java](http://haxe.org/doc/start/java).

It will generate some .java class and compile them into a .jar.

You can then either use the .jar as a normal Java jar, or use directly the Java classes. It's still under heavy development, so it may require some minor hacks, but its globally working great.